# How to delete a Firebase Storage file with flutter?

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm new to both Flutter and Firebase, so bear with me on this one.

I am trying to delete a File in my Firebase Storage using the file Url.

I have the full Url of the file and remove all characters excluding the file path.

Then I try to delete the file. From following other answers on here I use the command;
`FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).delete()`

Below is my code;

```
static void deleteFireBaseStorageItem(String fileUrl){

  String filePath = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-i-2345.appspot.com/o/default_images%2Fuser.png?alt=media&token=c2ccceec-8d24-42fe-b5c0-c987733ac8ae'
                  .replaceAll(new 
                  RegExp(r'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-2345.appspot.com/o/'), '');

  FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).delete().then((_) => print('Successfully deleted $filePath storage item' ));

}
```

The problem is the file never gets deleted.

I think I have tracked down where the problem is.

In the `.delete()` method there is a required 'app' and 'storageBucket' value.

When I run this function the values are null.

[image: See screen shot]

I find this confusing because in the same file i see this;

```
/// The [FirebaseApp] instance to which this [FirebaseStorage] belongs.
///
/// If null, the default [FirebaseApp] is used.
final FirebaseApp app;

/// The Google Cloud Storage bucket to which this [FirebaseStorage] belongs.
///
/// If null, the storage bucket of the specified [FirebaseApp] is used.
final String storageBucket;enter code here
```

From the documentation I can see maybe I need to use the 'Firebase core' plugin to make the app which links the bucket to that database. But there is not much specific to Dart & flutter.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

## Found Temporary solution

So there is not a method to convert the Url to a storage reference at the moment. Hopefully it will come out in a Firebase update.

Here was my hack

```
 static void deleteFireBaseStorageItem(String fileUrl){

String filePath = fileUrl
                  .replaceAll(new 
                  RegExp(r'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-2345.appspot.com/o/'), '');

filePath = filePath.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'%2F'), '/');

filePath = filePath.replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');

StorageReference storageReferance = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();

storageReferance.child(filePath).delete().then((_) => print('Successfully deleted $filePath storage item' ));
```

}

I know.... i know....

Ps 'dial-in-2345.appspot.com' is relevant to my app and you would need to change it.

Comment: Those values are normally read from the configuration file/data that you include in your app in this step of the setup: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup#configure_to_use_firebase

Comment: Thanks Frank. I ran through this setup and i assume most of that data is in the 'google-services.json' and 'GoogleService-Info.plist' files which i have installed. I can save files no problem. It just seems to be when deleting them.

Comment: Hmm.. that uses the exact same configuration. Ah wait, I see what's going on. You're passing a download URL into `child`, which won't work. Let me find the right method that can take a download URL and translate it to the correct `StorageReference`.

Comment: @earyhe, am I right that your trying to delete an image file (png)? Maybe the path to your image file is `"o/default_images/user.png"`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the temporary solution, I was stuck for two weeks, if it wasn't for your solution, I would had to wait till the much awaited feature comes up.

Comment: As frank said
    FirebaseStorage.instance
        .getReferenceFromUrl(imageData)
        .then((reference) => reference.delete())
        .catchError((e) => print(e));

works now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Update (2021-05-22):

`FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete()` should be used now.
`getReferenceFromUrl` that was suggested earlier seems to be gone from the API.

Update (2019-08-03):

According to [this PR](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/1208) there is now a [`getReferenceFromUrl` method](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage/getReferenceFromUrl.html) in FlutterFire that allows looking up a storage reference by its download URL.

---

Previous answer:

On Android you can call [`getReferenceForUrl()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/FirebaseStorage.html#getReferenceFromUrl(java.lang.String)) to get a `StorageReference` from a download URL, and a similar method exists on iOS.

But I can't find a corresponding method in the [FlutterFire  reference docs](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/FirebaseStorage-class.html). This unfortunately means that there is no way to map from a download URL back to a `StorageReference` in Flutter.

This sounds like an omission, so I recommend casting your +1 on this [feature request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/20458).

For the moment this means you'll need to have the relative path to the file in Cloud Storage to be able to delete it from Flutter. With that path, your current code would work.

Comment: Hmmm. ok so from my code snippet above I have already manipulated the download Url by removing unwanted characters with Regex. This leaves behind the file path in the 'filePath' variable. I then pass this into the child argument of the function. In the image above, the '_pathComponents' list variable does not contain the full download Url, but the path.... which should be correct ...right?

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a guarantee that the path to the image is 1:1 embedded in the download URL. I always treat the download URLs as opaque strings. But if you hard-coded the path to the image as `default_images/user.png`, does that work?

Comment: Frank you legend. **YES!! that worked**. Thank you so much. That's been bugging me for weeks! ok well it will be quite hard to manipulate that url string so i can dynamically delete files. I guess we all have to do that for now until the 'getReferenceForUrl()' feature is implemented. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

change filePath to

```
String filePath = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-21c50.appspot.com/o/default_images%2Fuser.png?alt=media&token=c2ccceec-8d24-42fe-b5c0-c987733ac8ae'
                  .replaceAll(new 
                  RegExp(r'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-21c50.appspot.com/o/default_images%2F'), '').split('?')[0];

FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).delete().then((_) => print('Successfully deleted $filePath storage item' ));
```

Answer (score 3):

I have implemented a cleaner code but same as @earyhe, which is using `Uri.decodeFull()` and `Path.basename()`. Tried and it worked.

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;


  Future<void> deleteImage(String imageFileUrl) async {
  var fileUrl = Uri.decodeFull(Path.basename(imageFileUrl)).replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');


final StorageReference firebaseStorageRef =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileUrl);
    await firebaseStorageRef.delete();
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

With respect to @Frank van Puffelen answer here is the code snippet to delete the file from Firebase storage with reference to the URL

```
  if (oldUrl != null) {
  var fileUrl = Uri.decodeFull(Path.basename(oldUrl))
      .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');
  StorageReference photoRef = await FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .getStorage()
      .getReferenceFromUrl(oldUrl);
  try {
    await photoRef.delete();
  } catch (e) {}
}
```

Complete method

```
Future<UserItem> uploadUserImage(String filePath, {String oldUrl}) async {
 if (oldUrl != null) {
  var fileUrl = Uri.decodeFull(Path.basename(oldUrl))
      .replaceAll(new RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');
  StorageReference photoRef = await FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref()
      .getStorage()
      .getReferenceFromUrl(oldUrl);
  try {
    await photoRef.delete();
  } catch (e) {}
}

Im.Image image = Im.decodeImage(File(filePath).readAsBytesSync());

// todo cleanup string formation
final StorageReference storageReference =
    FirebaseStorage().ref().child('user_images').child(
          DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString() +
              '.' +
              filePath.split(".")[1],
        );
final StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(
  File(filePath),
);

/// wait for upload to complete
await uploadTask.onComplete;

/// get the uploaded items url
String url = await (storageReference.getDownloadURL());

/// add the pic to FireStore Instance
FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
String token = user.uid;

/// adds the item to the corresponding token path
await _fireStore
    .document('$token')
    .setData({'userImage': url}, merge: true);

return await getUserData();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if (post.imageURL != null) {
    StorageReference photoRef =
        await FirebaseStorage.instance.getReferenceFromUrl(post.imageURL);

    await photoRef.delete();
  }
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps

Answer (score 2):

=== December 2020 ===

Great thank for the answers, this is just an update, because old ways led my app to crash.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path;

String fileUrl =Uri.decodeFull(Path.basename(i)).replaceAll(RegExp(r'(\?alt).*'), '');
StorageReference ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(fileUrl);
await ref.delete();
```

Comment: Thank you So Much, got this working answer after searching for hours!

Answer (score 2):

**3. 3. 2021**

I am not sure how was it in the past (because I am quite new to Flutter and Firebase), but currently it is quite simple. Suppose you want to delete an image from Firebase Storage. In order to do that you will write the following method:

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

//firebase Storage reference
  final _storage = FirebaseStorage.instanceFor(
      bucket: [your bucket address]);

Future<void> deleteImageFromDB(String imageUrl) async {
    var photo = _storage.refFromURL(imageUrl);
    await photo.delete();
  }
```

Comment: what happens when the delete operation has failed? Do we get an error?

Answer (score 2):

**August, 10 2021**

If you want to delete image from firebase you must have url of that image just like
:

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/ecommerce-c962d.appspot.com/o/images%2F2021-08-03T11%3A10%3A27.616369?alt=media&token=5310a745-9533-47ef-8de1-db876933ff6f
> Then you just have to pass that url inside of:

```
 Reference photoRef =await FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(imageUrl);
 await photoRef.delete().then((value) {
  print('deleted Successfully');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This function work very well for firebase storage link

```
static Future<bool> deleteFileFromFirebaseByUrl(String urlFile) async {
String fileName = urlFile.replaceAll("/o/", "*");
fileName = fileName.replaceAll("?", "*");
fileName = fileName.split("*")[1];
print(fileName);
StorageReference storageReferance = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref();
storageReferance
    .child(fileName)
    .delete()
    .then((_) => print('Successfully deleted $fileName storage item')); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instance of `StorageReference storageReference;` then initialize it like

```
storageReference = await FirebaseStorage.instance
                              .getReferenceFromUrl('photoUrl');
```

you must have photoUrl so that storageReference is pointed towards right image. Then just delete it like

```
storageReference.delete();
```

All done.

Answer (score 0):

With the latest breaking changes, this is the following straightforward method I've used.

1. Import the latest `firebase_storage` and all the other dependent updates it will require to your `pubspec.yaml`. currently this is the following for firebase_storage:

   ```
   dependencies:
      firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
   ```
2. import the package as follows:

   ```
   import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
   ```
3. Finally, within a try catch, you can do the following:

   ```
   try 
   {
     await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance.ref('/images/something.jpg').delete();
    } catch (e) {
     debugPrint('Error deleting $yourReference: $e');
   }
   ```