# How to delete image from firebase storage in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How to delete the image from firebase storage in the flutter

```
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: (){
                            Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Cancel"),
                              onPressed:  () {
                                Navigator.pop(context);
                              },
                            );
                            Widget continueButton = FlatButton(
                              child: Text("Continue"),
                              onPressed:  () async{
                                final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://djgwalior-15404.appspot.com/');
                                await storage.ref().child('birthday/'+snapshot.data[index].data['name']+'.jpeg').delete();
                                Firestore.instance.collection("birthday")

                                    .document(snapshot.data[index].documentID)
                                    .delete().whenComplete((){
                                  Navigator.pop(context);
                                  Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Booking Done")));
                                }).catchError((e){
                                  debugPrint(e);
                                });
                              },
                            );

                            // set up the AlertDialog
                            AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
                              title: Text("Delete Item"),
                              content: Text("Are you sure?"),
                              actions: [
                                cancelButton,
                                continueButton,
                              ],
                            );

                            // show the dialog
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return alert;
                              },
                            );                            },
                          child: Icon(Icons.delete, color: Colors.red,)),
                    ),
                  )
```

Error:

```
E/StorageException(11472): StorageException has occurred.
E/StorageException(11472): Object does not exist at location.
E/StorageException(11472):  Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
E/StorageException(11472): {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11472): java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not delete object",    "status": "DELETE_OBJECT"  }}
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:455)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.parseErrorResponse(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:435)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.processResponseStream(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:426)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:280)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.network.NetworkRequest.performRequest(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:294)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:70)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.ExponentialBackoffSender.sendWithExponentialBackoff(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:62)
E/StorageException(11472):  at com.google.firebase.storage.DeleteStorageTask.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@17.0.0:58)
E/StorageException(11472):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
E/StorageException(11472):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
E/StorageException(11472):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
E/flutter (11472): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(deletion_error, Object does not exist at location., null)
E/flutter (11472): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:564:7)
E/flutter (11472): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:302:33)
E/flutter (11472): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11472): #2      StorageReference.delete (package:firebase_storage/src/storage_reference.dart:152:10)
E/flutter (11472): #3      _Birthday_showState._view.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:getbookings/birthday_show.dart:225:118)
E/flutter (11472): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (11472): #4      _InkResponseState._handleTap (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:511:14)
E/flutter (11472): #5      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:566:30)
E/flutter (11472): #6      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:166:24)
E/flutter (11472): #7      TapGestureRecognizer._checkUp (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:240:9)
E/flutter (11472): #8      TapGestureRecognizer.handlePrimaryPointer (package:flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart:177:9)
E/flutter (11472): #9      PrimaryPointerGestureRecognizer.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart:436:9)
E/flutter (11472): #10     PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:73:12)
E/flutter (11472): #11     PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:101:11)
E/flutter (11472): #12     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:221:19)
E/flutter (11472): #13     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:199:22)
E/flutter (11472): #14     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:156:7)
E/flutter (11472): #15     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:102:7)
E/flutter (11472): #16     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:86:7)
E/flutter (11472): #17     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1136:13)
E/flutter (11472): #18     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1029:19)
E/flutter (11472): #19     _CustomZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:931:7)
E/flutter (11472): #20     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:233:10)
E/flutter (11472): #21     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:154:5)
E/flutter (11472):
```

Comment: Please check this out.
[Delete Firebase storage image in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170250/how-to-delete-a-firebase-storage-file-with-flutter)

Comment: The error you get says "Object does not exist at location". Are you sure the call you're making is using the right field "name" from the snapshot? Also, are you sure the file is still on the storage?

Answer (score 0):

The function to delete the object from storage is correct. You may want to verify if the path to the object is correct or if the object still exists.