# How to delete file from Firebase Storage in Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I tried the example from this post [How to delete a Firebase Storage file with flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170250/how-to-delete-a-firebase-storage-file-with-flutter/59890430?noredirect=1#comment105909520_59890430)

But it did not work. Here's what I tried:

```js
String filePath = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amct-47348.appspot.com/o/ClassificadoImages%2F1579839318515.jpg?alt=media&token=cd8880eb-8b37-45e4-8dc1-e75de0c5f7cb'
  .replaceAll(new RegExp(r 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amct-47348.appspot.com/o/ClassificadoImages%2F'), '').split('?')[0];

FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).delete()
  .then((_) {
    print('Successfully deleted $filePath storage item');
  }).catchError((e) {
    print("err: $e");
  });
```

And this what it returned:

```js
I / flutter(4920): err: PlatformException(deletion_error, Object does not exist at location., null)
```

Could use some ideas on why it returns an error, since it's exactly like the example. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase SDKs take the path of the file in the bucket where they're stored.  They don't take a URL, or a split URL.  They also don't take url-encoded strings.  The paths must be the plain string that was used to upload them.

Just a guess, but if you have the donwload URL that starts with

> https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/amct-47348.appspot.com/o/ClassificadoImages%2F1579839318515.jpg"

then the string path of the file is probably

> ClassificadoImages/1579839318515.jpg

That's what you should pass to `FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child()` to build a reference to work with it (since %2F is the encoded version of forward slash in a URL).

Comment: Thanks for your input. Was just following the example "hack" since it seems there is no official way of doing this in Flutter, as yet. Problem is to get a ref to the bucket path from the download url.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the url of the image you have stored in firesbase storageyou can use the

> **getReferenceFromUrl** method in **StorageReference **.

and then we can delete it using the reference.

```
FirebaseStorage.instance
    .getReferenceFromUrl(imageData)
    .then((reference) => reference.delete())
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: `getReferenceFromUrl` is not valid