# uploading image to firebase storage from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

i want to upload image to Firebase Storage, but I noticed most of the code available online (except documentation) has deprecated.
as i am new to flutter, I read documentation for image picker and firestore.
i was able to figure out image picker, but uploading in bucket of firestore is giving me the tough time.

below is the code for imagepicker,that i managed to do correctly:

```
 File _image;
     final picker = ImagePicker();
    
    Future getImage() async {
          final pickedFile =  await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
          setState(() {
            if (pickedFile != null) {
              _image = File(pickedFile.path);
    
    
            } else {
              print('No image selected.');
            }
    
          });
        }
```

now i dont know how to complete the upload to Firebase Storage function:

```
Future UploadImage(BuildContext context) async{

String filename = basename(_image.path);
firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage storage = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance;



// how to proceed?


}
```

Comment: The documentation for Firebase Storage has up-to-date code samples for uploading: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#uploading-files

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you have the file name. I will use your code only for that.

```
String filename = basename(_image.path);

Reference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("<Bucket Name>/$filename");
```

After having a reference to your bucket now you need to put the file in that bucket.

```
final UploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);
```

Now you need the url of the image. For that you need to wait till the upload completes.

```
final TaskSnapshot downloadUrl = (await uploadTask);
```

Now after this is done you can get the URL of the file using

```
final String url = await downloadUrl.ref.getDownloadURL();
```

This answer is for the version number `firebase_storage: ^5.2.0`

Hope this helps. Let me know if any doubts.

Comment: yes, it worked, thanks a ton. i had uploaded image to firestore before, but that code was depreciated. and i had an issue in reading the documentation being a beginner. i thank you for explaining each step. cheers!!

Comment: No problem happy to help.

Comment: @pradyot1996 is there a way on how to rollback the upload if by mistake I choose a big file ?

Comment: @mohamed https://stackoverflow.com/a/54175316/8244668 found this to delete a file. Have not tried it by myself yet.