# Flutter : delete (firebase storage)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I'm trying to delete an image from firebase storage use this code, but it doesn’t  work

```
final FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage(storageBucket: 'gs://momyt-meet.appspot.com/uploads');
await storage.ref().child("imageurl").delete();
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete a Firebase Storage file with flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170250/how-to-delete-a-firebase-storage-file-with-flutter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete to a file of any type, you can use this method, I hope it helps :

```
static Future<dynamic> deleteFileByUrl({@required String url}) async {
    return FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete();
  }
```

Comment: PlatformException(deletion_error, Object does not exist at location., null, null)
 still get this error

Answer (score 0):

`String filePath = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-21c50.appspot.com/o/default_images%2Fuser.png?alt=media&token=c2ccceec-8d24-42fe-b5c0-c987733ac8ae'
.replaceAll(new
RegExp(r'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/dial-in-21c50.appspot.com/o/default_images%2F'), '').split('?')[0];``</code>`

FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(filePath).delete().then((_) => print('Successfully deleted $filePath storage item' ));