# 2 different urls created while uploading files to firebase storage and cloud firebase

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Iam uploading files to firebase storage and the referenced url in cloudfirestore. Uploading and showing the file in the app works perfectly.
But when i try to delete an image, i get an error:
"[firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference."
I found out that the urls in firebasestorage and in cloudfirestore are not the same:

FirebaseStorage URL: **https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/project-db68d.appspot.com/o/images%2FNvbKO7fZxv5KXsPy1lPJovsxiKXN%2Fimage_cropper_1662715164516_out.jpg?alt=media&token=2d591f0d-d2ee-4640-8133-57cea509d3d7** //Does not show the file in the browser

CloudFirestore URL: **gs://project-db68d.appspot.com/images/NvbKO7fZxv5KXsPy1lPJovsxiKXN/image_cropper_1662715164516_out.jpg** // Shows the file in der browser

I don`t understand why 2 different urls are created and how to fit it, when i print the url it shows the url from firestorage?

This is my code:
Iam working with ImagePicker, flutter_image_compress and image_cropper, latest versions flutter and packages

```
Future<File?> getImageFromCamera()async{
  File receivedImageFromCamera = await _pickImageFromDevice.pickSingleImageFromGallerieOrCamera(ImageSource.camera);
  File receivedCroppedImage = await _croppImageFromDevice.imageCropper(receivedImageFromCamera);
  File? compressedFile = (await _imageCompressor.compressFile(receivedCroppedImage));
  return compressedFile;
}

static Future<String> uploadFile(String destination,File file)async{
  final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(destination);
  final result = await ref.putFile(file);
  final String fileUrl = (await result.ref.getDownloadURL()).toString();
  return fileUrl;
}


   if(compressedFile==null) return;
  final fileName = basename(compressedFile.path);
  final destination = 'images/$chatId/$fileName';
  final fileUrl = await UploadFileToStorage.uploadFile(destination,compressedFile);
```

Comment: Answer on the two URLs below. If you need help with deleting the file, edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both URLs are valid references to the file, but they have a different protocol. The `gs://` protocol is specific to Google Cloud Storage, and is supported by very few clients. The `https://` protocol is universal and supported almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for response,according to these article on stackoverflow: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170250/how-to-delete-a-firebase-storage-file-with-flutter], i used an old or wrong method: ' final ref = await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("img").child(id!).child(file);
      await ref.delete();' It works now with  'FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url).delete();' and you are right, the urls were not the problem.